# SQL - Update command with subquery and linked server

Tags: sql-server, subquery, alias, linked-server

I'm currently attempting to run an update on a table using a linked server

Ex.

```
update table1 a
set a.column1=(select Count(b.column1) FROM linkedserver.databse.table b)
where a.column2=b.column2
and a.column3=b.column3
```

My problem is:

The multi-part identifier "linkedserver.databse.table.column" could not be bound.

The only way i can see this working is with aliases and i know the server has the appropriate access to the linked server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the schema in your query

try using

```
LinkedServer.Database.Schema.Table
```

Or

```
LinkedServer.Database..Table   (if schema is dbo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not certain it's the cause of your problem, since I would expect to see a different error, but your syntax should be:

```
update a
   set a.column1=(select count(b.column1) 
                    from linkedserver.databse.table b
 where a.column2=b.column2
       and a.column3=b.column3)
  from table1 a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use UPDATE FROM statement and 4 parts table name when you're working with linked servers.

```
update table1
set column1=(select Count(b.column1) FROM linkedserver.databse.dbo.table b)
from table1 a
where a.column2=b.column2 and a.column3=b.column3
```